# Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function - date format related

Tags: sql-server

The query below returns the following error: 
"Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

When it runs correctly, it returns the case_id and the data between the 8th and 9th tab characters in the ct.case_text column.

The parameters for the `SUBSTRING` function in the query do evaluate to positive integers. `b.received` is a DATETIME column

```
SELECT TOP 1000 b.case_id,
SUBSTRING(ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(
          CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, 
              CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.
                    case_text) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(
              CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, 
                  CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1
      ) + 1) - CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.
          case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), 
                ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text, CHARINDEX(CHAR(9), ct.case_text) + 1) + 1) + 1) 
            + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1)) 
FROM case_id b
INNER JOIN case_text ct ON b.company_id = ct.company_id
  AND b.case_id = ct.case_id
  AND ct.case_text_seq = 1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM case_text ct1
    WHERE ct1.case_id = ct.case_id
      AND ct1.case_text_seq = 3
    )
  AND b.received BETWEEN CAST('2014-12-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2015-01-29' AS DATE)
  AND b.b13_code IS NOT NULL
  AND ct.description IS NULL 
  AND b.case_id IN (4222729, 2840639, 3359716, 3365915)
```

If I comment out the line below, the error disappears.

`AND b.received BETWEEN CAST('2014-12-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2015-01-29' AS DATE)`

Does anyone know why commenting out that line will cause this to run correctly? That condition is necessary to identify the full set of data; the case_id filter is used currently for an initial test.

Comment: Good grief that is nearly impossible to decipher. A string splitter would be a lot easier to deal with here.

Comment: ...or stop stuffing multiple pieces of data into a single column. Yuck.

Comment: @AaronBertrand's advice is the BEST approach.

Comment: Since you said you can't create a splitter you are stuck with figuring out what is going on with that. I can't even begin to decipher that. You have nearly 1,000 characters with nested charindex. It is no surprise it fails for some values. Without tables and sample data there is nothing anybody can do to help with the problem of the date check.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of using a string splitter. You can read more about them here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

I personally prefer the Moden splitter. It has some shortcomings and limitations but is super fast if you stay within the boundaries.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 b.case_id
    , s.Item
FROM case_id b
INNER JOIN case_text ct ON b.company_id = ct.company_id
  AND b.case_id = ct.case_id
  AND ct.case_text_seq = 1
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(case_text, CHAR(9)) s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM case_text ct1
    WHERE ct1.case_id = ct.case_id
      AND ct1.case_text_seq = 3
    )
  AND b.received BETWEEN CAST('2014-12-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2015-01-29' AS DATE)
  AND b.b13_code IS NOT NULL
  AND ct.description IS NULL 
  AND b.case_id IN (4222729, 2840639, 3359716, 3365915)
  AND s.ItemNumber = 8
```

For completeness sake here is the code for the DelimitedSplit8K function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
```

One last but very important comment, you have top 1000 but there is no order by. Without ordering your results you have no way of knowing which rows you will get.

Comment: +1 but I still don't know why you continue to insist this is super fast, or maybe I don't know what fast is relative to - [for this specific problem, it didn't come anywhere near the fastest in my tests](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up).

Comment: LOL Aaron. Any of them are faster than the typical while loop we all see over and over. The Moden version is pretty fast, not saying it is the fastest. I have been using it for a quite a while and haven't had performance issues using it. Your article is comparing the older 4k version and not the newer 8k version. There were some pretty beefy performance upgrades in that version. I guess I need to "recreate" your testing code with the latest and greatest Moden piece.

Comment: Did you click the link? I tested his "latest" once he figured out which one his "latest" actually was. And I only tested the 4K version because, well, 8K is pretty useless if you have Unicode text.

Comment: Ummm yeah I clicked the link. Here is the first couple lines. ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplitN4K]
(@pString NVARCHAR(4000), @pDelimiter NCHAR(1))

Comment: Please read beyond the first two lines of the function code I posted. I got that code [from here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) - is there yet another newer, really new-for-sure version of the function that I've missed? As you'll see that I explained in the post that I re-tested based on Jeff's insistence that I hadn't tested the most recent version of the code. The article explains all that, and I explained above why I didn't test the 8K version - we don't all have the luxury of only using varchar, since we need to take input from actual users.

Comment: Do you know, for example, if the OP's `ct.case_text` column is `varchar` or `nvarchar`? If it's the latter, they may lose data.

Comment: (The Unicode version I tested, `The New DelimitedSplitN4K Function.sql`, is not listed in Jeff's post but it is included in the downloads near the bottom of the article. All I did was remove comments and adjust some whitespace. Last modification is documented as `Rev 07 - 06 May 2011` so I'm pretty I tested the most recent version.)

Comment: Fair enough. It seems that this particular topic is one that gets you going. I did mention it has some shortcomings. I certainly don't want get into an argument over this. It is hardly worth it and I am ill-equipped to go head to head. :) Pretty sure we both agree that avoiding delimited data is the best approach anyway.

Comment: Like I said, it works, and have no objection to it. I take exception to the misleading advice that states or implies it's the fastest approach.

Comment: If I had the access to create a function, I would use something like this, but I don't have the permission.